# Why is my 301/302 stuck in a redirect loop?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

this is my first question here so I hope I'm asking correctly. Apologies if I give too much or too little info.

I'm currently trying to gradually migrate my existing website www.essexmums.org to www.essexmums.com - the old site is a mix of html and wordpress but I'm moving it to a wordpress multisite. This involves moving a section at a time and creating 301 redirects to the new site.

I previously used this code to redirect www.essexmums.org/blog to www.essexmums.com/blogandnews so that every article is redirected to the same page within the new installation:

```
Redirect 301 /blog http://www.essexmums.com/blogandnews/
```

and it worked fine. I'm now trying to do the same with redirecting www.essexmums.org/recipes to www.essexmums.com/recipes but everything I do seems to get me stuck in a redirect loop. I'm trying them out with 302 redirects rather than 301 but basically I have tried both:

```
Redirect 301 /recipes http://www.essexmums.com/recipes/

Redirect 301 /recipes http://www.essexmums.com/recipes
```

and then also have tried to redirect a single page to see if that worked, such as:

```
Redirect 302 /recipes/tabbouleh-for-toddlers/ http://www.essexmums.com/recipes/tabbouleh-for-toddlers/
```

but this gets stuck too and I get a 'too many redirects' page.

What am I doing wrong? I'm sure it must be something stupid and entirely my fault so would welcome any suggestions!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are they both running off the same website? You can do this to avoid the loop:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.essexmums.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/recipes/
RewriteRule ^ http://www.essexmums.com/recipes/ [R=301,L]
```

I guess your first worked because the new URL is different.

You only need the first line once, the other three are needed for each redirect. It says if the host is not `www.essexmums.com` and the address is `/recipes/` then redirect to `http://www.essexmums.com/recipes/`.

Comment: Thanks, the one I'm redirecting from is www.essexmums.org and the one I'm redirecting to is www.essexmums.com so different URLs.

Is there anything else I need to add to that? I've just put in that code and nothing seemed to happen so I'm not sure if I should be adding a 302/301 redirect to it too.